# Loop for the user input in bash

Tags: bash, loops, input

I am trying to build loop for the user input until I get a specific input for example I want to stop the loop when the input = 4 and print siiiiii
but the problem is the program stuck in the loop
how can I set a new value for the loop input ?

```
#!/bin/bash

value=4

echo Enter the number:
read $input
while [ $input !=  $value ]
do
    echo "The input must be between 1 and 4"
    read input2
    input = $input2
done

echo siiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

value=4

echo Enter the number:
while read input; do
    if [ "$input" = "$value" ]; then break; fi
    echo "The input must be between 1 and 4" >&2
done

echo siiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

You could also write:

```
while read input && [ "$input" != "$value" ]; do
    echo "The input must be between 1 and 4" >&2
done
```

You might prefer to use `-eq` and `-ne` since you are doing integer comparisons, as this gives you additional error messages.  Whether or not those error messages are useful is a design decision:

```
while read input && ! [ "$input" -eq "$value" ]; do
    echo "The input must be between 1 and 4" >&2
done
```

The 4 main issues with your original code are: failure to quote variables, incorrect attempt at the assignment `input = $input2` (you cannot have space around the `=`), incorrect use of `$` in the `read $input` command, and failure to use the standard `while read varname` idiom.  There are probably some other minor issues as well, but those jump out.